# Convert datetime to date using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have datetime like:

`01-Jan-10 12:00:00 AM` I want to get only `01-Jan-10`.I do not know how to convert it. Anyone know help me please, Thanks,

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? Are you saying you have a string in that format and want to put it into a DateTime variable or are you saying you have a DateTime variable and want to get a string out with only the date and no time?

Comment: See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `DateTime` object and want to get the string in that format, use `myDateTime.ToString("dd-MMM-yy")`.  If you have a `DateTime` object and want to return a new `DateTime` object that is just the date component, use `DateTime.Date`.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to note that, since MMM results in a culture specific  value that the OP should specify the culture if they really always want the string `Jan`

Comment: @Maly, when you look at answers to your questions you'll see a small gray checkmark underneath the votes for each answer.  When you have an answer that you consider to correctly address your question, please click the checkmark to accept that answer.  In order to assist the StackOverflow community you should do this for all of your questions that have received helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today; //or whatever
string dateString = dt.ToShortDateString();
```

You can also use `ToString()` to format it however you like. In your case, it would be:

```
string dateString = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-YY");
```

Answer (score 0):

use method `DateTime.ToShortDateString();` or `DateTime.ToLongDateString()`